# Logon to website the Login and password

Tags: vbscript

I try to create a VBS script, what started automatically an website. This part could I solve.
But now I need to put in this script the function login as
And that is the point i stay stucked.

So I hope you can help me.
Here is the script I take to open the website

```
Dim objExplorer


 Set objExplorer = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

 Do While (objExplorer.Busy)
 Wscript.Sleep 250
 Loop

 objExplorer.TheaterMode = False
 objExplorer.AddressBar = True
 objExplorer.MenuBar = True
 objExplorer.StatusBar = True
 objExplorer.ToolBar = False
 objExplorer.Resizable = True


 objExplorer.Height = 600
 objExplorer.Width = 800
 objExplorer.Left = 0
 objExplorer.Top = 0
 ' objExplorer.FullScreen = True
 objExplorer.Silent = False
 objExplorer.Visible = True


 objExplorer.Navigate https://mi-xxxxx-xxx-xxxxx.xxx.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/login.aspx

objExplorer.Login = User
ObjExplorer.Password = Password

 wscript.sleep 6000

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
 objShell.Run("taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe /T")

 Set objExplorer = nothing
```

I hope there is a easy way to come to an result.

Many thanks for your Help in this case.
best Regards
Martin

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to automate the login via the GUI try inspecting the login process with something like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/). That should give you the actual request that's passing the credentials from the client to the server. With that information you can use an [XMLHttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453379.aspx) to automate the login:

```
url = "https://mi-xxxxx-xxx-xxxxx.xxx.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/login.asp"

user = "..."
pass = "..."
credentials = "username=" & user & "&password=" & pass

Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0")
req.open "POST", url, False
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
req.send credentials

If req.status = 200 Then
  'login successful
Else
  'login failed
End If
```

You may need to adjust the `url` and `credentials` strings according to what Fiddler revealed. You may also need to encode username and/or password with something like this:

```
Function Encode(ByVal str)
  Set re = New RegExp
  re.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.~-]"

  enc = ""
  For i = 1 To Len(str)
    c = Mid(str, i, 1)
    If re.Test(c) Then c = "%" & Right("0" & Hex(Asc(c)), 2)
    enc = enc & c
  Next

  Encode = enc
End Function
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion.  Are you aware of any alternative that won't require software installation?  I'm in a work environment that prohibits software installation but we can still run executables.  I would love to incorporate this into some of my already existing scripts.

Comment: @BHart No. You need an SSL proxy to break up the SSL connection in order to inspect the HTTPS requests. I don't think it's possible to set up something like this without admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I find an great way to come to need result.

```
WScript.Sleep 5000
WshShell.SendKeys "******"
WScript.Sleep 3000
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 3000
WshShell.SendKeys "*********"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 3000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

wscript.sleep 10000
```

So this task is solved.
many thanks for all your commands.
best Regards
martin